# Parent and child-spawn don't seem to share mapped memory. Windows

Tags: python, process, mmap

I have a weird problem.

The below code works, if I open two `cmd` and simply run each script from the commandline via alt-tabbing.

```
# share1.py
import numpy
ram = numpy.memmap("bla",shape=4096,dtype=numpy.uint8,mode="w+")

for y in xrange(0,4096):
    for x in xrange(0,4096):
        ram[x]=65+y

print ram
```

-

```
# share2.py
import numpy
ram = numpy.memmap("bla",shape=4096,dtype=numpy.uint8,mode="readwrite")

for y in xrange(0,4096):
    for x in xrange(0,4096):
        m=ram[x]
        print m,

print ram
```

This works! `share2` continuously prints out the changes `share1` makes.

But when I spawn the same code from python directly, instead of `cmd`, suddenly this doesn't work anymore and I don't understand why.

I use `psutil` to spawn an empty python process and feed it code via `stdin`. I ignore `stdout` so any `print` in the spawn eventually outputs on the main `cmd` I'm using to run the script.

`share1` outputs the proper numbers it has set, while `share2` only ever outputs 0, as if it didn't get to see the mapping at all. Please note that this also happens using regular `mmap` (not numpy`s).

What am I doing wrong?

*(edit: accidentially put `share2` at the beginning of the last paragraph, instead of `share1`.)*

Comment: Zero responses? Is it so obvious and I'm just not seeing the tree inmidst all the wood?

Comment: After more digging and trying, I've found out that it works if I pass the program through via the `-c` command line argument. It still makes no sense to me though and I rather use `stdin` instead...